# Проблема с SSL сертификатом: в браузере отображается, а через curl - ошибка

Tags: python, curl, ssl, aiohttp, domain

Взял ssl сертификат на reg.ru. Поднял апи на python aiohttp.
Часть кода с сертификатами

```
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
ssl_context.load_cert_chain(certfile='rootCA.pem', keyfile='rootCA.key')
web.run_app(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=443, ssl_context=ssl_context)
```

Если заходить через браузеры на сайт по https - все ок.
Если делаю запросы через postman/curl - ошибка. Ошибка курла:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Почему такое может быть?

так же попробовал поднять на фласке, результат такой же.

Comment: Возможно на стороне клиента не подгружены root-сертификаты или цепочки центров сертификации. Одно из решений - установить эти сертификаты на клиенте. Второе решение, - это в curl игнорировать предупреждение, реализуется через опцию insecure: `curl --insecure https://example.com/`

Comment: В качестве клиента пробовал разные машины - результат один. А апи нужно для доступа из iOS приложения, через curl только тестирую, потому вариант с игнорированием не подходит. Тем не менее - спасибо.

Comment: зачем брать сертификат, если есть letsencrypt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть предположение, что дело именно в сертификатах от reg.ru. Воспользовался certbot'ом от Let's Encrypt и все заработало.